# TNULL in Red-Black Trees for Python

Tags: python

Hi I was just looking at some examples of R-B tree codes and I was wondering if there was a reason the new attribute TNULL is made and used instead of just using None. On that note, TNULL is not a built-in 'replacement' for None right? I looked through some python documentation but couldn't find TNULL in them. The following is what I'm referring to which can be found on https://www.programiz.com/dsa/red-black-tree

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        self.parent = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.color = 1


class RedBlackTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.TNULL = Node(0)
        self.TNULL.color = 0
        self.TNULL.left = None
        self.TNULL.right = None
        self.root = self.TNULL
```

Please tell me if there's some misunderstanding I have. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've added in the part where they declare a TNULL!

Answer (score 1):

TNULL is used because sometimes we might check the left or right of the TNULL Node, and so basically TNULL exists so the code can be more elegant, while not breaking the program because `None` has no attribute `left` or `right`